# pointer to function syntax and usage

Tags: objective-c, c

I apologize if this was asked many times.
I'm trying to understand why both of this works fine without any warnings or other visible issues (in Xcode):

```
int testFunctionAcceptingIntPointer(int * p) {         
    return *p = *p +5;
}

void test() {
    int testY = 7;
    typedef int (*MyPointerToFunction)(int*);
    // Both this (simply a function name):
    MyPointerToFunction functionPointer = testFunctionAcceptingIntPointer;
    // And this works (pointer to function):
    MyPointerToFunction functionPointer = &testFunctionAcceptingIntPointer;
    int y = functionPointer(&testY);
}
```

Comment: You define `functionPointer` twice in your `test()` you should receive an error for that.

Comment: no no ANY of this. One of it is commented when testing

Comment: `MyPointerToFunction functionPointer = testFunctionAcceptingIntPointer;` is syntactic sugar of the other version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code works fine without warnings both ways because a function designator is converted to a function pointer

```
MyPointerToFunction functionPointer = testFunctionAcceptingIntPointer;
```

unless it is the operand of the address operator

```
MyPointerToFunction functionPointer = &testFunctionAcceptingIntPointer;
```

(or `sizeof` and `_Alignof`).

In the first assignment, you don't use `&`, so the automatic conversion is done, resulting in a function pointer of appropriate type, in the second, you explicitly take the address, resulting in a function pointer of the appropriate type.

Comment: The fun thing about the automatic conversion to a pointer is that you could also call `int y = ************functionPointer(&testY);` if you like asterisks. After each dereference, it's converted to a pointer again ;)